# Increment digit value in String

Tags: java, regex

So, i have some String with digits and another symbols, and i want to increment the value of each digit at 1. For example:   "test1check2" from this String i want to recieve "test2check3". And can i make this only with method "replaceAll"? (i.replaceAll("\d", ...) something like that)?, without to use methods such like indexOf, charAt...

Comment: if you have test12, should it become test13 or test23 ?

Comment: it must be for every digit, digit is from 0-9, so must be test23

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with a simple replaceAll(...), you'll have to write a few lines like:

```
Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)"); // EDIT: Increment each digit.

Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher("test1check2");
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find())
{
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
}
matcher.appendTail(result);
return result.toString();
```

There's probably some syntax errors here, but it will work something like that.

**EDIT:** You commented that each digit must be incremented separately (abc12d -> abc23d) so the pattern should be changed from (\\d+) to (\\d)

**EDIT 2:** Change `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` as required by `Matcher` class.

Comment: +1 for a great answer; however, I had to change 'StringBuilder' to 'StringBuffer'. Just in case anyone has the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Id be inclined to do something like this

```
string testString = new string("test{0}check{1}");
for (int testCount = 0; testCount < 10; testCount++)
{
   for (int checkCount = 0; checkCount < 10; checkCount++)
   {
   console.WriteLine(string.FormatString(testString, testCount, checkCount)); 
   }
}
```

I know the question has now been answered but to address the comments, in Java you can do this:

```
for (int testCount = 0; testCount < 10; testCount++)
{
   for (int checkCount = 0; checkCount < 10; checkCount++)
   {
      String s = String.format("test%scheck%s", testCount.ToString(), checkCount.ToString()); 
   }
}
```

Comment: it's a Java question, not c#.