# Incrementing only the digits from an alphanumeric string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to increment the digits of an alphanumeric string.

Example 1:
ABC000DEF will be ABC001DEF

Example 2:
ABCDEF000 will be ABCDEF001

It's incrementing based from the format of the string input.

Comment: Wich is the result of incrementing A9A?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, it would be adjusted to A10A if possible.

Comment: And A999A become A101010A or A1000A?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO sweeet!! XD it will be `A1000A` if not `ABC000` will become `ABC111`

Comment: A1000A is the expected output,

Comment: Sounds like a job for either regex or writing code to manually pull out runs of numeric characters into their own string. What have you tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment digit value in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453365/increment-digit-value-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number from the string then increment it and put it back, e.g. using `String.replaceXxx()` and `Integer.parseInt()` etc.

If you want to increment multiple independent numbers, try this:

```
String input = "ABC999DEF999XYZ";

//find numbers
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[0-9]+" );    
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );   
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

//loop through all found groups
while( m.find() )
{
  //get the length of the current number
  int minLength = m.group().length();

  //parse the found number, increment and reformat it to the given min length
  String format = "%0"+minLength+"d";
  String incrementedNumber = String.format( format, Integer.parseInt( m.group() ) + 1 );

  //append the match and all text before to the StringBuffer
  m.appendReplacement( sb, incrementedNumber );
}

//append the rest of the input to the StringBuffer
m.appendTail( sb );

//prints ABC1000DEF1000XYZ
System.out.println( sb );
```

Comment: Which will change "000" to "1"

Comment: @KevinKal well he could still apply a format, e.g. by checking the length of the extracted number string and reformatting it accordingly.