# Dynamic incrementation of all numbers within a String

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Is there any Java solution of replacing a digit in a String other than getting the digit using a matcher, increment it by one and replace it?

"REPEAT_FOR_4" will return "REPEAT_FOR_5"
"REPEAT_FOR_10" will return "REPEAT_FOR_11"

I would like to do it in one line with regex and replace, not by recomposing the String as "REPEAT_FOR_" and add the number after incrementation.
Thank you!

Later edit: I would like to know how to replace a number with the following one in a String.

Comment: Yes, with `Matcher#appendReplacement`

Comment: Technically, you can't "replace" anything in a `String`, because objects of `String` are immutable. But you can create a new `String` containing the old prefix plus Integer.valueOf(suffix) + 1.

Comment: Yes, I know. I will update my question. Generate a new String :)

Comment: You could use an IntStream, map it to an Integer, then produce a list of strings in one line of code.

Comment: give an example of input and expected output

Comment: In this case, regex will only make the code longer, not shorter.

Comment: What is the pattern of the String? The number is always at the end, always present, The splitter is `_`? Could you enumerate more condition ?

Comment: No, this only an example. I would like to know solutions for replace any number in a String with the following one.

Comment: @rianna, then update your example. This is not clear for me (and others too). You need to specify a pattern, or patterns of String. (or a number anywhere...)

Comment: Thanks, Pavneet! Sorry for duplicating the questions.

Comment: don't be sorry , it was a good question though  :)

Comment: don't be sorry , it was a good question though :) , you can try this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453365/increment-digit-value-in-string , , plus the below given answers are also great examples too

Comment: Revising my comment from yesterday to use iterate() instead of generate().This does not satisfy the requirement of not recomposing the String, but it will generate any number of Strings in one line: List<String> strings = IntStream.iterate(0, x -> ++x).limit(100) .mapToObj(x -> "REPEAT_FOR_" + Integer.toString(x)) .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @rianna doesn't my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use regex but here is the solution in one line. Considering your string remains the same.

```
public String getIncrementedString (String str){
return ("REPEAT_FOR_" + (Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(11))+1));
}
```

Comment: OP says: **not by recomposing the String as "REPEAT_FOR_" and add the number after incrementation**

Comment: but it seems his issue was he wanted to do it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
String ss = "REPEAT_FOR_4";
int vd = Integer.valueOf(ss.substring(ss.length() - 1));
String nss = ss.replaceAll("\\d",String.valueOf(vd+1));

System.out.println(nss);
```

output:

> REPEAT_FOR_5

with regex: if the digit is not at the end of the string.

```
    String ss = "REPEAT_5_FOR_ME";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ss);
    m.find();
    String strb = m.group();
    int vd = Integer.valueOf(strb);
    String nss = ss.replaceAll("\\d",String.valueOf(vd+1));

    System.out.println(nss);
```

output:

> REPEAT_6_FOR_ME

Base on the issue raised in the comments comments i think this solution with regex will help.

```
public static String convStr(String str){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    m.find();
    String strb = m.group();
    int vd = Integer.valueOf(strb);
    return str.replaceAll("\\d",String.valueOf(vd+1));
  }
```

Comment: But if the number is not on the end of the string, it will not work. I came up to this solution: String nrToBeReplaced =  CharMatcher.DIGIT.retainFrom(value);
        int nextNr = Integer.valueOf(nrToBeReplaced) + 1;
        return value.replaceAll(value, String.valueOf(nextNr));

Comment: @rianna i have updated my answer with regex and it solves the issue you raised

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it's possible. using regex `Pattern` and `Matcher`, here's what you will need to do:

```
    String str = "REPEAT_FOR_4";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(s, String.valueOf(1+ Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
    String updated = s.toString();
    System.out.println(updated);
```

This is [**a working Example**](http://ideone.com/a3xtIL) that returns `REPEAT_FOR_5` as output.